# Get the ErrorLevel in Jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I created/modified a Resource translator Tool in C# that check the Format in all my resource files in a project.

the program returns an integer.
0 means no Format issue has been found. 
A number > 0 is the count of all format issues found.
Less than 0 is an error like Folder not found etc..

I need to integrate this process in our Jenkins build pipeline (I need to stop the build if the return is not 0)

I modified the Jenkins Script and it's working pretty good, the only problem is that I can't catch up the ErrorLevel.
I want like to throw an Eco blah-blah if the return is 0 and something else if the return is != 0.

any help how to do that.

This what I did so far, as I said it's working and the build stop if the return value is not 0, but I need to catch that value somehow to know for example the Total count of the Format issues I have etc..

```
try{
        stage('Check Translation'){
            buildResult.checkTranslationSuccssfull = false
            // Clean project
            bat "${MSBuildPath} ${WORKSPACE}\"\\Translator\\ResxTranslator.sln\" /t:Clean,Build /p:Configuration=\"Release\" /p:Platform=\"x86\" /p:BuildProjectReferences=false >>${OutPutBuildLog}"
            // Build reference SmartFramework
            bat "@Echo Off"
            bat "@Echo [Check all Resx format]"
            bat "@echo"
            bat "${WORKSPACE}\\Translator\\bin\\Release\\ResxTranslator.exe /checkForamt ${WORKSPACE}\\DataBlock\\SmartFramework"           
            buildResult.checkTranslationSuccssfull = true           
        }
}
catch(Exception ex){
    echo "test ${env.errorlevel}"
    echo "Check Translation failed. Check BuildServer solution."
    echo ex.toString()
    currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE' // mark as unstable to continue with pipeline
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [returnStatus flag](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#-bat-%20windows%20batch%20script)

> Normally, a script which exits with a nonzero status code will cause the step to fail with an exception. If this option is checked, the return value of the step will instead be the status code. You may then compare it to zero, for example.

And here's how you could use it

```
def returnCode = bat (
    script: "${WORKSPACE}\\Translator\\bin\\Release\\ResxTranslator.exe /checkForamt ${WORKSPACE}\\DataBlock\\SmartFramework",
    returnStatus: true
)
```

It wouldn't fail the build or throw exceptions so you can handle it properly and do whatever you need.

Comment: returnStatus: true That IS what I was missing thanks a lot